# OpenOffice.org Lowercases second capital letter

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

How can I turn of the feature in OpenOffice.org Calc which converts CCleaner to Ccleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools -> AutoCorrect -> Options and disable `Correct TWo INitial CApitals`.

This also applies to LibreOffice.

[Source](http://plan-b-for-openoffice.org/intro/topic/disable-double-initial-capitals-correction)

Answer (score 1):

Format > AutoCorrect > AutoCorrect Options... > Options tab

Uncheck both columns for "Correct TWo INitial CApitals."

Comment: Two ways to skin the cat, apparently.